# Making a class act as string in Python when you have both str and unicode

Tags: python, object, unicode, subclass

Disclaimer: I am using Python 2.6 for a lot of weird reasons. It is what it is.

I'm trying to make an object act as a string with properties like this:

```
class Setting(str):

    def __new__(cls, value, source):
        return super(Setting, cls).__new__(cls, value)

    def __init__(self, value, source):
        self.value = value
        self.source = source
```

This works rather nicely. Scarily nice. ;)

BUT: I need to support both unicode and str objects. So what I would ideally like to do is extend basestring. Unfortunately, probably for completely logical reasons; just changing the super class to basestring does not work and gives the error:

```
TypeError: The basestring type cannot be instantiated
```

Anyone have any idea how I could go about fixing this? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `basestring` because Python won't allow it simply, it's  an abstract C only class and can only really be used in Python for a `isinstance` or similar  call.

In this case what I would recommend is a generic approach, create a class with two variables and override any special operators to get the desired result (ie make it act like a str):

```
class Setting:
    def __init__(self, value, source):
        self.value = value
        self.source = source

    def __add__(self, rhs):
        #keeping the object immutable
        return Setting(self.value + rhs, self.source)
```

However in the interests of extreme python code, for which I cannot think of a single use case (there will always be a better way), here is a workaround:

```
class Setting(object):

    def __new__(cls, value, source):
        #pick the correct base class
        base_class = str if isinstance(value, str) else unicode
        #construct new Setting class with correct base
        new_type = type(cls.__name__, (base_class,), dict(cls.__dict__))
        return base_class.__new__(new_type, value)

    def __init__(self, value, source):
        self.value = value
        self.source = source
```

The idea is just to dynamically create a class with the correct base based on the type of the value given.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with sublcassing a builtin to build a ducktype that for example, reimplements a method that is required for another class that expects a certain implementation (like I have to reclass Decimal to a float subclass that reimplements `__repr__` for SimpleJSON serialization. I also have had to extend `str` so that I can overload `match` semantics (from `re`) for example.

Comment: Your right, there is nothing inherently wrong with subclassing builtins, I can't remember my logic for that now. In the interests of clean code though there usually is a better way, although I do agree that sometimes a small addition is just the best way. I've changed the answer since that opinion didn't really matter to the question at hand.